# Django - Database query with condition in group_by

Tags: django, database, group-by, distinct, django-queryset

I've the following models:

```
class UsersRoles(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='USER_ID')
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, db_column='ROLE_ID')
    room= models.ForeignKey(Rooms, db_column='ROOM_ID')
    d_begin = models.DateTimeField(db_column='D_BEGIN')
    d_end = models.DateTimeField(db_column='D_END')
```

,

```
class Roles(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME', max_length=45)
```

and also the django User model.

So, I want to retrieve the `UsersRoles` for the `Room` 3 being the `Role` id equal to 5.

Since there are multiple `UsersRoles` that fulfil this conditions, I want to group the `UsersRoles` by the `User` id, returning only the one that has the `lastest d_begin date`, but if exists one in which `d_begin is NULL that's the one to return`.

After these conditions, I would like to group_by the User name.

To get the UsersRoles of the room 3 with role 5, I would do:

```
users_roles = UsersRoles.objects.filter(room__id=3, role__id=5)
```

My problem is to group them by User id, getting for each user the UserRole with d_begin equal to NULL if there is one, and if not, it would be the one with the latest date.

To order them, I would do `users_roles.order_by('user__name')`.

Comment: i find it helpful to first write the raw SQL you would need for more complicated queries like this; then try to apply it to the ORM, if possible. otherwise you at least have a raw SQL you could just use.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it. My problem is that I would like to have a queryset to use with django Paginator. Is it possible with a raw SQL?

Comment: Complex queries will be available in [django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/). for now there is no such functionality to make conditional aggegation or group_by. You must use raw SQL or `extra` method.

Comment: For more complex "or" queries like this, you'll want to get familiar with the Django "Q" object: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects